# Is it better to chain CSS classes or name them separately for modular purposes?

Tags: css, oocss

For example, which is better:

**Method 1 (name classes separately):**

```
/* CSS */

.textbox-red, 
.textbox-green {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   border-radius: 10px;   
}

.textbox-red { color: #900; }
.textbox-green { color: #3c3; }

/*HTML*/

<div class="textbox-red"></div>
<div class="textbox-green"></div>
```

OR ------------

**Method 2 (chain classes):**

```
/* CSS */

.textbox {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.textbox.text-red { color: #900; }
.textbox.text-green { color: #3c3; }

/*HTML*/

<div class="textbox text-red"></div>
<div class="textbox text-green"></div>
```

What is a better practice among the two?

Comment: You shouldn't call classes or IDs things like "text-red" as this is stating a design decision in a class name which may change later e.g. that colour may have to be changed to purple so you change it in the CSS then you have a purple text box called "text-red". So in this case you could call your text boxes "text-one" or some such.

Comment: Noted. This is just for example. I would normally use "text-alert" or "text-success" or something of the sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion is that you should use modular css - 
You could also combine classes instead of linking them:

```
/*CSS*/
.textbox {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.text-red { color: #900; }
.text-green { color: #3c3; }

/*HTML*/

<div class="textbox text-red"></div>
<div class="textbox text-green"></div>
```

That way you can reuse the red and green colors in cases when you want to have a red background without a textbox. This way you can re-use your code more and you have a loose coupling between your textbox and text-color

Comment: Or as @BillyMoat said: use text-alert or text-warning. But anyways, my point is that these generic classes can be reused when they are not linked to a textbox

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go with method 2.  That way you can swap out text-red or text-green easily for text-blue or text-yellow and still keep the underlying style for your text.  Basically, method 2 allows for more flexibility and maintainability, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the modular approach gives you the most flexibility. The modular css pattern is also used in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) where flexibility is very important.

Answer (score -2):

First better if you making style for IE6, because this browser dont support second method.

Comment: Regardless of your english, your comment actually contains false information. IE6 DOES support chaining ( e.g. Method 2 ), but it can get little bit tricky when calculating selector specificity & order. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626370/chaining-css-classes-in-ie6-trying-to-find-a-jquery-solution